# Import Julia module with different name

Tags: julia

In Python, you can import a module with whatever name you want by using the `as` keyword.  Is there an equivalent to this in Julia?

Obviously you can just do

```
import moduleWithReallyLongName
M = moduleWithReallyLongName
```

Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now it's just

```
import moduleWithReallyLongName as M
```

Answer (score 9):

```
import moduleWithReallyLongName
const M = moduleWithReallyLongName
```

Please note the usage of const. By a rule of thumb any global variable in Julia should be type stable, otherwise you will observe reduced performance.

Another option is the package `ImportMacros.jl` (https://github.com/fredrikekre/ImportMacros.jl)

```
using ImportMacros
@import moduleWithReallyLongName as M
```